# Android Volley Request Response not in order

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

I am making multiple Volley StringRequests.

The **requestfriendlist** method fetches a list of profiles related to "Naruto". The **requestimagelink** method fetches Images for each profile it got in the previous method result.However the reponse (imagelink) I am getting is not in order from the **requestimagelink** method is not in order.

For Example -

Request[1,2,3,4]

Response[2,1,4,3] or any other order.

Please help me fix this issue.

Attaching Code Snippet

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomImageAdapter(this, imageList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    requestfriendlist("Naruto");
}
private void requestfriendlist (String profilename)
{
    String uri = String.format(Config.URL_REQUEST_FRIENDS + "?current_user=%1$s", profilename);
    Log.d(TAG + "uri", uri);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse (String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.d(TAG + "friends", response);
                        JSONArray jResult = responseObj.getJSONArray("req_users");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for(int i = 0; i < jResult.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jresponse = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                            String profile = jresponse.getString("userid");
                            friendlist.add(profile);
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < friendlist.size(); i++)
                            requestimagelink(friendlist.get(i));
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error" + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

private void requestimagelink (final String profilename)
{
    String uri = String.format(Config.URL_REQUEST_IMAGE + "?userid=%1$s", profilename);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "uri" + uri);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                //response from the server
                @Override
                public void onResponse (String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvprofilejson)).setText(response);
                        Log.d(TAG, response);
                        JSONArray jResult = responseObj.getJSONArray("photos");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jResult.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jresponse = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                            ImageClass img = new ImageClass();
                            img.setThumbnailUrl(jresponse.getString("name"));
                            img.setTitle(profilename);
                            imageList.add(img);
                            //imagelinks.add(jresponse.getString("name"));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error" + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to link your profiles to their images using a hashMap:

```
    ArrayList<String> friendlist = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
    Keeps the profiles' images. Later in your arrayAdapter, where you want show thumbnail image, you must
    get corresponding ImageClass from of profile with profileName. If the result is null means that the image
    is not loaded yet, otherwise you can use the ImageClass object to retreive profile's image.
*/
HashMap<String, ImageClass> profile_img_Hash = new HashMap<String, ImageClass>();

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomImageAdapter(this, imageList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    requestfriendlist("Naruto");
}
private void requestfriendlist (String profilename)
{
    String uri = String.format(Config.URL_REQUEST_FRIENDS + "?current_user=%1$s", profilename);
    Log.d(TAG + "uri", uri);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse (String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.d(TAG + "friends", response);
                        JSONArray jResult = responseObj.getJSONArray("req_users");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for(int i = 0; i < jResult.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jresponse = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                            String profile = jresponse.getString("userid");
                            friendlist.add(profile);
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < friendlist.size(); i++) 
                            requestimagelink(friendlist.get(i)); 

                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error" + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

private void requestimagelink (final String profilename)
{

    //This snippet will prevent re-downloading
    if(profile_img_Hash.get(profilename) != null) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Optional. Not neccessary..!
            }
        });
        return; //Because this profile's image is loaded.
    }


    String uri = String.format(Config.URL_REQUEST_IMAGE + "?userid=%1$s", profilename);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "uri" + uri);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                //response from the server
                @Override
                public void onResponse (String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvprofilejson)).setText(response);
                        Log.d(TAG, response);
                        JSONArray jResult = responseObj.getJSONArray("photos");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jResult.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jresponse = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                            ImageClass img = new ImageClass();
                            img.setThumbnailUrl(jresponse.getString("name"));
                            img.setTitle(profilename);
                            imageList.add(img);
                            //imagelinks.add(jresponse.getString("name"));

                            //Before notifying the adapter we have to put the img into our hash map.
                            profile_img_Hash.put(profilename, img);

                            //Remember, in you getView(..) method of your adapter, you have to get image from 
                            // profile_img_Hash by profileName as key. If the returned result was null do nothing
                            // If the returned value was not null you can use the ImageClass to provide profile's 
                            // image. :)
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error" + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
    );
    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```

Keep in mind, in your arrayAdapter's getView(...) method you must load profile's image right from `profile_img_Hash` with profile name as key like this:

```
ImageClass img = profile_img_Hash.get(profilename);
if(img != null){
   //row's imageView.setBitmap(img.getBitmap());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not I was looking for. I need a way to keep it fast enough but by maintaining the order as well. Can you explain how to link with the image to the item in friendlist and maintain the order? (By using map ???? )Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the code in answer. Maybe it's not the whole solution but it can give you some ideas about how to link your profile's to their images.